# Why is my .NET Core @keyframes code not working in Visual Studio?

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor

I'm new to .NET Core and wanted to know if I'm doing anything wrong or missing anything to get my `Background-clip: text;` to work, like it does in any other platforms...

I've tried `Background-clip: text;` and `-Webkit-Background-clip: text;` and nothing seems to work. It says that the text value is not valid for Background-clip

Here's my code: Style.css

```
.text-container p {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 150px;
    background-image: url("https://s31.postimg.cc/yaze1agjv/abstract-background-canvas-249798.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: animate 30s linear infinite;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 17%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        background-position: left 0px top 10px;
    }

    40% {
        background-position: left 800px top 10px;
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<html class="backimg">
    <body>
        <p class=text-container> Hello World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to debug this problem on another text editor, and this code works fine. Is there something wrong with .NET Core when it comes to background-clip: text;?

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2m6pwvqo/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right CSS syntax for keyframes animations, but it's not called like that in a Razor syntax web page.

you can put extra @ sign and try with below:

```
@@keyframes animate{

}
```